# How to Store and Call Only Certain UTM Parameter Key and Value Pairs

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink, query-string, key-value

I am trying to get only certain key value pairs of UTM parameters from inbound viewers and then build a new url search string to send additional query string parameters elsewhere on a page button click.

Here is what the inbound URL looks like:

```
https://testsite1.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/index.html?utm_source=sna&utm_medium=soc&utm_campaign=pro&utm_term=us&utm_content=951431114
```

I only need to collect the `utm_content=` parameter's value but I'm not sure how to get this last part properly to store it. Here is what I currently have:

```
 const queryString = window.location.search;
  if (queryString !== null) {
    //const p = new URLSearchParams(s);

    const queryStringParamVal = queryString[5].value; //not working?
```

I'll then rebuild a new URL with the `utm_content`'s value and append some new query string parameters on a button click URL.

```
const link = "https://testsite2.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/index.html? " + "merchantID=12345&userID=654321&productID=" + queryStringParamVal
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to parse it:

```js
var queryString = "utm_source=sna&utm_medium=soc&utm_campaign=pro&utm_term=us&utm_content=951431114";
var utm_content = queryString.match(/utm_content=([^&]+)/)[1];
console.log(utm_content)
```

You can also parse the whole string into an object:

```js
var queryString = "utm_source=sna&utm_medium=soc&utm_campaign=pro&utm_term=us&utm_content=951431114";
var parameters = Object.fromEntries(queryString.split("&").map(el => el.split("=")));
console.log(parameters)
console.log(parameters.utm_content)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work when extracting the query string parameters from the inbound url. I'm seeing this error in the console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`

Comment: what's the querystring?